# using instance variables in chartkick, gives empty chart, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, instance-variables, chartkick

I've used `chartcick` to go through datasets.

Now I want to only show the values of some instance variable in a column chart.

the values are each bound to a different instance variable.

```
@type1_total = @trx2_1kg.to_f + @sam_1kg.to_f + @nest_1kg.to_f + @nav23_1kg.to_f
```

If I add this `@type1_total` variable to the chart the chart shows up empty without any columns.

I've also tried to make another variable in the controller, like this.

```
        @data_for_types = [
        {
            name: "Type_1", 
            data: [@type1_total]
        }

]
```

And in the view `<%= bar_chart @data_for_types %>`

That also gives an empty graph.
Is it not possible to show values from instant variables on charts?
I don't see anything about it in the documentations?

Comment: the `data` must be an array of hashes, key is displayed on the horizontal axis while the value is the actual value for that key. Example: `data: [{'2017-01-01' => 12}]` will display "2017-01-01" on the horizontal axis and the value will be 12.

Comment: @MrYoshiji also it will accept a nested `Array` as well e.g. `[['2017-01-01',12]]` so `data: [['Total',@type1_total]]` would be acceptable